# How to uninstall or remove gem from localhost which is installed from git source

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have installed gem from git source, now i am trying to uninstall it. I tried gem uninstall GEMNAME but it's not uninstalling it. How to uninstall it?

Comment: How have you installed it? The easiest way is to either switch to another gemset or remove the directory with it’s sources manually.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have installed it adding line gem "themes_for_rails", :git => 'my_git_source', :branch => 'master' to gemfile. What do you mean by  remove the directory with it’s sources manually?

Comment: Why would you need to remove it? It won’t make any harm. Unfortunately, I have no cleaner words to restate “remove the directory manually.” Ruby version manager you use, like rvm/rbenv, downloads and unpacks all gems into `~/.rvm/....`. Find your unwanted gem directory and remove it.

Comment: Yes, uninstalled by removing gem directory. Thanks again @mudasobwa .